# никак не могу разобраться с FSM на aiogram 3.2.0

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

всем привет! столкнулся с проблемой, после ввода номера телефона ничего не происходит(

```
class Form(StatesGroup):
    surname = State()
    phone = State()
    email = State()


@dp.callback_query(lambda callback_query: callback_query.data == 'callback')
async def start_form(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Как вас зовут?")
    await state.set_state(Form.surname)


@dp.message()
async def process_surname(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(surname=message.text)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Какой у вас телефон?")
    await state.set_state(Form.phone)


@dp.message()
async def process_phone(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(phone=message.text)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите вашу почту:")
    await state.set_state(Form.email)


@dp.message()
async def process_email(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_data = await state.get_data()
    surname = user_data.get('surname')
    phone = user_data.get('phone')
    email = message.text
    ADMIN_ID = '00000000'
    await bot.send_message(ADMIN_ID, f"Фамилия: {surname}\nТелефон: {phone}\nEmail: {email}")
    await state.finish()
```

хотелось бы чтобы бот провёл опрос и скинул все данные как надо мне в лс

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: А фильтры где в хендлерах? Как бот будет определять, что это именно этот стейт? Вы документацию читали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Документация](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/dispatcher/finite_state_machine/index.html)

В хендлеры фильтры добавьте как в приведенных примерах

**UPD:**

```
class Form(StatesGroup):
    surname = State()
    phone = State()
    email = State()


@dp.callback_query(lambda callback_query: callback_query.data == 'callback')
async def start_form(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await state.set_state(Form.surname)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, "Как вас зовут?")
    


@dp.message(Form.surname)
async def process_surname(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(surname=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Form.phone)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Какой у вас телефон?")
    


@dp.message(Form.phone)
async def process_phone(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(phone=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Form.email)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите вашу почту:")
    


@dp.message(Form.email)
async def process_email(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_data = await state.get_data()
    surname = user_data.get('surname')
    phone = user_data.get('phone')
    email = message.text
    ADMIN_ID = '00000000'
    await bot.send_message(ADMIN_ID, f"Фамилия: {surname}\nТелефон: {phone}\nEmail: {email}")
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: @dp.message(Form.phone)
#код...
#
#
@dp.message(Form.phone)
#код...
#
#
@dp.message(Form.email)
#код...
#
#
@dp.message(Form.phone)
#код...
#
#
я сделал так и в консоль получил:
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=401653212 is not handled. Duration 0 ms by bot

Comment: Вроде да, точный ответ получите сами, протестируйте, будет виднее и сможете подогнать под себя, как вам нужно. Но суть уловили.

Comment: У меня пишет is not handled( никак не могу разобраться в данной проблеме

Comment: Перепишите весь код по аналогии как в документации, сложно сейчас сказать где ошибка. Сначала обработчик колбеков, в колбеке Form.name, далее обработчик Form.name и далее по аналогии. Ошибку если перевести, станет понятно, что что то не обрабатывает, вероятно неверно установили фильтры

Comment: я разобрался! спасибо за помощь!!! очень помогли)))

Comment: @HIveK добавил пример кода, и поменял местами установки состояний с отправкой сообщений. Проверьте, осталась ли ошибка

Comment: Если ответ помог, отметьте его как правильный

Comment: отметил) ещё раз спасибо!!!